# Can we determine definiteness of matrix by looking at eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given matrix A,

if all the eigenvalues of A are positive, then we can say that A is positive definite.

If all the eigenvalues of A are negative, can we say that A is negative definite or If one or more of the eigenvalue has different signs, does that mean that A is indefinite?

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric, you can, otherwise not in general. For example, take $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -100 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $v=(1,1)^T$, then $v^T Av = -98$.

Comment: Does your definition of "positive definite" assume that $A$ is symmetric?

Comment: yeah A being symmetric

Comment: More general than symmetric, you can if A is normal.